# ERROR: Unable to automatically install 'OpenSpecFun'

Tags: packages, julia

Saludo cordial. Intento agregar el paquete "Distributions" (u otros):

`(@v1.6) pkg> add Distributions`

Y obtengo:

```
ERROR: Unable to automatically install 'OpenSpecFun' from 'C:\Users\cescalac\.julia\packages\OpenSpecFun_jll\1Zaof\Artifacts.toml'
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base .\error.jl:33
  [2] ensure_artifact_installed(name::String, meta::Dict{String, Any}, artifacts_toml::String; platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, verbose::Bool, quiet_download::Bool, io::Base.TTY)
    @ Pkg.Artifacts C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\Artifacts.jl:445
  [3] ensure_all_artifacts_installed(artifacts_toml::String; platform::Base.BinaryPlatforms.Platform, pkg_uuid::Nothing, include_lazy::Bool, verbose::Bool, quiet_download::Bool, io::Base.TTY)
```

... y errores similares...

Desinstalo todo, instalo de nuevo. Persiste el error. Les agradezco desde ya si me ayudan con la solución. Versión de Julia 1.6.4.

Buen resto de semana.